# How to get rid of box when clicking/tapping on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, web, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to get rid of a box that appears only on mobile devices when a user taps/holds a link(button). I've noticed when I set the active state color to the color I want the font to be it appears to set the background color as well.

```
a:active{outline: none; color: #fff;}
```

Here is how the links look like before and after they are clicked on mobile (looks fine on desktop).

[Button before it is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InJq5.jpg)
[Button after it is tapped/held](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r7LB.jpg)

Comment: try `a { user-select: none; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to remove the color property for mobile only. To achive that you can use `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` property in css which will load the css for all devices that have `max-width` of `600px`.  Here you can find more info on that https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: If I get rid of the color property or make the color transparent for mobile via a media query then it works and the box doesn't appear but the font doesn't show either. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: To be able to answer that I would need more code from you. What you can do is open dev tools in your browser and inspect css for desktop and mobile and make changes that you find suitable.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Phantom! I ended up just changing the color of the active link to a dark blue using the media query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);

-webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

Keep in mind that this will not work for all users.

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately, it didn't get rid of that white box in the 2nd link :( thank you though!